# Use list to generate lowercase letter and number in python

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am trying to use a list such as: 
[(1,4),(2,2)]

To get:
[(a,4),(b,2)]

I am trying to use 'string.ascii_lowercase' how would I accomplish this in Python3, this is for a coding challenge to get the least characters possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Rather than getting other people to solve coding challenges for you, wouldn't it be easier to just not do them to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to solve it for you, but I'd suggest you look into the `chr` and `ord` functions. Note that the ASCII code for "a" is 97, so to convert 1 to "a" you would have to add 96 to it.

Comment: Thanks! Just needed somewhere to start with it!

Comment: Happy to help! :) Feel free to upvote or accept my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow the suggestion given by [B.Eckles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39966723/3738882) above as you would learn better and probably find a shorter (character-wise) solution.

However, if you want to stick with using *string.ascii_lowercase*, the code snippet below could be useful to start from:

```
import string 

a = [(1,4),(2,2)]
b = []
for (first, second) in a:
    b.append(
        (string.ascii_lowercase[(first-1) % len(string.ascii_lowercase)],
         second))

print b
```

In this case, the printed solution would be:

```
[('a', 4), ('b', 2)]
```

I have inserted the module (i.e. *% len(string.ascii_lowercase)*) to avoid out-of-bound accesses. Just be careful that the value 0 would produce 'z' in this way.

Hope it helps!